# Broken jobs links in various headers/footers

Tags: bug, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs, blog, footer

This link in the footer for the [Stack Overflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/) 404s since jobs is no more:
[image: A blog footer with a link labelled "Jobs"]

---

Same with these links in the footer for [stackoverflowsolutions.com](https://stackoverflowsolutions.com/):

[image: A footer with links labelled "Jobs" and "Developer Jobs Directory"]

---

These links in the footer for [stackoverflow.co](https://stackoverflow.co/) also 404:

[image: A footer with links labelled "Jobs" and "Developer Jobs Directory"]

---

These links in the header for [insights.stackoverflow.com](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey) and [contests.stackoverflow.com](https://contests.stackoverflow.com/) 404 as well:

[image: "Developer Jobs" header item]

---

(I've combined all of these into one bug report since otherwise it would get unwieldy to manage 4 separate, very similar, questions)

Comment: We've got eyes on this and will removing the left over links, thank you for the report!